# Can I use EF-S lenses on Canon 6D?

Tags: lens-mount, canon-6d

I use a Canon 70D with a Canon EF-S 17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM lens, and it gives a nice, very beautiful video. But, I think it is time to jump in to the full frame world.

Can I use my lens with Canon 6D?

Answer (score 2):

In short, No.

Canon APS-C or cropped sensor bodies have more distance between the mount and the mirror because the mirror is smaller in the APS-C body. A few wider angle EF-S lenses take advantage of this travel and extend components further back into the body at certain zoom and focus positions than a standard EF lens. So, if you try to put an EF-S lens on a full-frame body, the back of your lens might hit the mirror at certain focal length and focus distance settings. However, you can put an EF lens on an APS-C body without problem (well, at least no physical mounting problems). So, at least you can upgrade your lenses knowing that they will always be backward-compatible with your other camera(s).

In review:

EF-S Lens and APS-C -> YES! 
EF-S and full frame -> NO 
EF and APS-C -> YES! 
EF and full frame -> YES!

Comment: Just to clarify, the extra space is available because the mirror is smaller, not because the mirror is mounted farther away from the lens. Being smaller, the bottom edge of the mirror doesn't reach as far forward as the mirror flips up.

Comment: @Caleb Thanks, I've added a note to clarify this in the answer.